# Find the string in array which doesn’t contain the character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
let wordarray=[“defeat”,”dead”,”eaten”,”defend”,”ante”];
word =“defantmsi”;
posarray=“entfdenis”;
```

I am new to JavaScript and in a code I stuck at a point. Actually I want to compare both ‘word’ and ‘posarray’ and find the missing characters in ‘posarray’ i.e., ‘m’ and ‘a’ and then I have to find the string and its position in the ‘wordarray’ which doesn’t contain those characters(m and a). So how can I do this by using only JavaScript?

The expected output will be the string that doesn’t contain the charcter m and a that is defend.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you solve a simpler version of the problem, for example, determining if a single specific character is located in a string?  You could then build on that, drawing each single character from another string.

Comment: What do you want as an expected output from ur array?

Comment: You should ask questions not ask for someone to give you the entire code solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you your example code

```js
let wordarray=["defeat","dead","eaten","defend","ante","something"];
word ="defantmsi";
posarray="entfdenis";
function findMissingCharacters(str1,str2){
 let result = [] //array which will be returned
 for(let letter of str1){
    //check if str2 doesnot contain letter of str1
  if(!str2.includes(letter)) result.push(letter);
 }
 return result;
}
let missing = findMissingCharacters(word,posarray);
//filtering the wordarray
let strings = wordarray.filter(word =>{
  //this boolean will be returned
 let contains = false;
 missing.forEach(letter => {
    //check if any of letter in missing is in word
  if(word.includes(letter)) contains = true;
 })
  //we don't want strings for which contains is true
 return !contains;
})
console.log(strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

First we get the missing character from `word` by comparing it with `posarray`. Than we filter `wordarray` by using `every` and `includes` to check for `and` condition

```js
let wordarray=['defeat','dead','eaten','defend','ante', 'xyzam'];
let word ='defantmsi';
let posarray='entfdenis';

let missing = word.split('').filter(e=> !posarray.includes(e))


let op = wordarray.filter(e=> !missing.every(el=>e.includes(el)))


console.log(op)
```

Comment: `dead` `ante` `eaten` contains `a`. I am not sure whether he wants all the  of the letters not included or any one of them.

Comment: @MaheerAli `‘wordarray’ which doesn’t contain those characters(m and a)` to me this means the words which do not contain both `a and m`

Comment: @maheer ali basically I want that when I compare word and array then the missing letter (in posarray that is m and a ) comes as a result and then I have to find in array that the string which doesn’t contain the missing character